# Copy music from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to iPhone5s iOS 8.1

Tags: rhythmbox, music, iphone

I have a problem in copying music to my iPhone 5s (iOs 8.1) from my Ubuntu 14.04. On connecting the iPhone to my laptop via a usb chord, I can see a folder representing the iPhone. But I can't find a folder representing the music in the iPhone.

CopyTrans Manager helped copying music to iPhone from Windows. It was not working with Ubuntu. I tried opening the iPhone with Rhythmbox. But it wasn't showing any playlist or music from the iPhone.

Please recommend an ubuntu alternative for CopyTrans Manager.

Comment: Have you tried VLC Media Player? The version I use (2.1.4 on Ubuntu 14.04) started showing extensive list of devices and locations in the side panel in playlist view.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/607426/syncing-music-between-ubuntu-and-iphone-does-not-work/608311#608311

Answer (score 1):

[Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) could be useful. You can install it with the following command line help.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:banshee-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

For more info, go for the [ubuntu official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone).

Comment: Doesn't work with ios 9

Answer (score 0):

[aTunes](http://www.atunes.org/), [Floola](http://www.floola.com/home/) and [Eina](http://eina.sourceforge.net/) may be some good linux alternatives for CopyTrans Manager. [more here.](http://alternativeto.net/software/copytrans-manager/?platform=linux)

Answer (score 0):

PWNTunes works for iOS 8 and 9. It is a jailbreak tweak which allows you to drag and drop music to/from the "My Music" folder of your iPhone, just like on an Android phone or mp3 player.

This requires you to have a jailbroken iPhone.
Right now, iOS 8.4, 9.0, 9.0.1, 9.0.2, (but not iOS 9.1) can be jailbroken. If you're running iOS 9.1, you will need to downgrade to 9.0.2 (if Apple's still signing it), before jailbreaking.

To jailbreak iOS 8.4/9.0 is simple:

iOS 8: Use the Taig jailbreak tool, available from: http://www.taig.com/en/

iOS 9: Use the Pangu jailbreak tool, available from: http://en.pangu.io/

Once jailbroken, search for "PWNTunes" in cydia.