# Syncing music between Ubuntu and iPhone does not work

Tags: 14.04, sync, rhythmbox, banshee, iphone

Ubuntu 14.04 and iPhone 5s. Connecting iPhone via USB cable mounts the device and I can open it in Ubuntu. Syncing photos with Shotwell works fine. Both Rhythmbox and Banshee also recognize the iPhone and pretend to be able to sync with it. By this I mean they go through the motions of syncing and even claim that the sync is complete yet the music app on the phone remains empty.

When connecting the iPhone to the PC, I get the "Lockdown (-3)" error that has been talked about extensively in other threads and have followed all advice to no avail. Solutions that seem to have worked for versions of iOS <5 (e.g. as suggested in the above duplicate suggestion) no longer work with new versions.

Is there anyone here with the same experience who has managed to get the music sync to work properly?